# Explain with the aid of sample data and pseudo-code how this could be achieved

Tags: database

A database trigger could be used to implement the following business rule:
If the mark entered is less than 35% then an overall grade of FAIL is recorded. When all
4 marks are entered then the average mark is calculated and a grade of PASS or FAIL
recorded.
For a PASS the average mark must be 40% or more with no single mark less than 35%
otherwise a FAIL is recorded.

Comment: Are you seriously asking for the people to give an algorithm without you did try anything ?

Comment: because am still knew to stack overflow and programming thats why i did not post an algorithim,